# ImageJ Macro: setOption("Changes",false); not preventing 'Save Changes' prompt

Tags: imagej, imagej-macro

I'm working on an ImageJ macro that iterates through a list of images, applies transformations, and saves the transformed images. To avoid unnecessary 'Save Changes' prompts, I've included the line `setOption("Changes", false);` within the loop to reset the 'changes' flag of the original (unprocessed) image.

However, despite using this line, I am still prompted to save changes for each image in the loop. I would appreciate any thoughts about why this is happening and how I can resolve it.

**Minimal working example (edited):**

```
macro "Minimal working example demonstrating the 'Save Changes' prompt issue" {

// Create a new folder for Target images
    NewFolder = "C:\\Path\\Of\\Choice" + File.separator + "Target_Images" + File.separator;
    File.makeDirectory(NewFolder);

// Create three new images
    newImage("Reference.tif", "8-bit Black", 256, 256, 1);
    Reference_Image = getTitle();
    newImage("Target1.tif", "8-bit Black", 256, 256, 1);
    Target_Image = getTitle();
    saveAs("tiff", NewFolder+Target_Image);
    newImage("Target2.tif", "8-bit Black", 256, 256, 1);
    Target_Image2 = getTitle();
    saveAs("tiff", NewFolder+Target_Image2);
    files = getFileList(NewFolder);
  
// Select points on the Reference image
    var xpoints = newArray(50, 97, 139, 201);
    var ypoints = newArray(41, 104, 151, 187);
    selectWindow(Reference_Image)
    makeSelection("point", xpoints, ypoints);

// Select corresponding points on the Target image and add them to ROI
    selectWindow(Target_Image)
    makeSelection("point", xpoints, ypoints);
    run("ROI Manager...");
    roiManager("Add");

// Create a new folder for Registered images
    NewFolder2 = "C:\\Path\\Of\\Choice" + File.separator + "Registered_Images" + File.separator;
    File.makeDirectory(NewFolder2);

// Iterate through the list of Target images
  for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    open(NewFolder + files[i]);
    Target_Image = getTitle();
    
    // Select the previously added ROI
    roiManager("Select", 0);
    setOption("Changes",false); // resets the 'changes' flag of the current image
    
    // Use the `Transform -> Landmark Correspondence` plugin
    run("Landmark Correspondences", "source_image=Target_Image template_image=Reference_Image transformation_method=[Least Squares] alpha=1 mesh_resolution=32 transformation_class=Affine");
  
    // Save the transformed image in the "Registered_Images" folder
    title = getTitle();
    saveAs("tiff", NewFolder2+title);
  }
  
// Close all opened images and the ROI manager
  while (nImages>0) { 
    selectImage(nImages);
    close(); 
  }
  close("ROI Manager");
}
```

**Additional information:**
ImageJ version: 1.54f;
Operating System: Windows 10

**Expected outcome:**
I expect that using `setOption("Changes", false);` should prevent the 'Save Changes' prompt for each unprocessed image in the loop.

**Actual outcome:**
Despite including the line, I am still prompted to save changes for each unprocessed image.

**Attempts to solve the issue:**
I have tried including the `setOption("Changes", false);` line outside the loop as well, but still it doesn't prevent the 'Save Changes' prompt.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please post a *minimal working* ImageJ macro-code example that shows that the 'Save Changes'-dialog is shown.

Comment: @Herbie I replaced the code snippet with a minimal working example. When I run it, sometimes it shows the dialogue, sometimes it doesn't. I don't know what makes the difference.

Comment: When are you prompted for the changes? When you call "close" Maybe you should do the changes after the "saveAs" or do it in your while loop that closes everything.

Comment: Sorry but this is not a _minimal_ working ImageJ macro-code example. If you like to get some help, then please make it as easy as possible for someone who is willing to help. The above code is really much too convoluted. Why do you include run("Landmark Correspondences", ...). Is it the reason for the problem? If not, …

Comment: In the above code, why do you again use setOption("Changes",false);. I'd been asking for a *minimal working* ImageJ macro-code example that **shows** the 'Save Changes'-dialog.

Comment: @matt The "close" function triggers the dialogue window, and despite I tried to fix it by setting the option to false in the while loop, the issue continued. Placing the line after "SaveAs" only affects the transformed images (which I was never prompted for changes), not the unprocessed ones. However, your suggestion led me to set the option in both the for loop and the while loop, which appears to be the solution. I'll do more tests to confirm if it works, and in case I'll post the solution and credit your input.